# Mysql through ssh often can't connect or timeout

Tags: mysql, ssh-tunnel, mariadb

I have a MariaDB server (10.0.12) on a machine (Ubuntu 14.04) that other servers connect to through ssh for security purpose.

The ssh tunnel is openned via autossh like so:

```
autossh -M 3306 -f -Ng -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 mariaDB@server-ip
```

Unfortunately I often end up with 'can't connect' or 'Lost connection' errors:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

or

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0.
```

Here is some additionnal info as it might help:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show global variables like '%timeout';
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 30       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout            | 30       |
| net_write_timeout           | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout           | 3600     |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout    | 60       |
| wait_timeout                | 3600     |
+-----------------------------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Netstat output while doing `telnet 172.0.0.1 3306`:

```
netstat -naptu|grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5249/ssh        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46701         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46712         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46702         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46647         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46704         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46705         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46703         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46709         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      1 37.187.91.194:52674     172.0.0.1:3306          SYN_SENT    5109/telnet     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46706         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      5249/ssh
```

Telnet ends up timing out:

```
telnet 172.0.0.1 3306
Trying 172.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Is your SSH session timing out or is this failure occurring when you try to connect?

Comment: Try a telnet to 172.0.0.1 on port 3306. telnet 172.0.0.1 3306 Also see if it is listening netstat -naptu|grep 3306

Comment: What are the various timeouts for SSH connections and MySQL connections.  I have seen instances where the mysql client timesout while waiting on the ssh tunnel to connect.  In many cases this was due to reverse DNS lookups on the server side of the connection. You can disable these reverse DNS lookups in sshd's config files.

Comment: It seems to listen. I edited my question with the netstat output

Comment: @Andrew I had nothing set up in my sshd_config except `TCPKeepAlive yes` I'm going to add `ClientAliveInterval 60` and `ClientAliveCountMax 99999`

Comment: @jeffatrackaid timeouts for MySQL are shown in my question. As for ssh, it's the defaults. Is there a way to display them? Because there's nothing but `TCPKeepAlive yes` in sshd_config… Nothing about DNS in sshd's config files neither? Are they activated by default eventhough nothing is mentionned in the config file?

Comment: Setting `ClientAliveInterval 60` and `ClientAliveCountMax 99999` didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I've been struggling with this issue for most of the day: an SSH tunnel for MySQL just wouldn't get a response and `netstat` on the remote host showed `SYN_SENT` (from `127.0.0.1` on an ephemeral port to `127.0.0.1:3306`).

For me, the problem was that `iptables` was running but wasn't configured to allow loopback connections (sidenote: if anyone knows **why** that's a sensible default, I'd love to find out!) and, as such, the connection (the SYN packet) from the SSH daemon to MySQL was being dropped by `iptables`.

The fix is as simple as adding a `-i lo -j ACCEPT` rule in your `INPUT` chain before any global `DROP` rules. For me this was `iptables -I INPUT 4 -i lo -j ACCEPT` but this will vary depending on your existing rules.

Credit for helping me with this one goes to this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/319267

**Edit:** Don't forget to save your iptables changes afterwards!